# trying to compile after using eclipse and having import problems

Tags: java, javac

hi
i'm using ubuntu and i have a little project with several packages i wrote in eclipse.
when i am trying to compile (run javac) from the terminal i get numerous errors like:

```
Writeable.java:14: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class IllegalFilterArgumentException
location: class oop.ex1.filters.Writeable
        throw new IllegalFilterArgumentException();
```

now in eclipse everything was fine. i was told its because i need to run javac from a directory that can see all java files in my project, but it didn't work. any ideas? thanks

Comment: How did you set your class path.  There is no default so at a minimum you need something like `-cp .`

Comment: @Peter: If no classpath is set, it defaults to the current directory, is my experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using packages (as you are, from the error message), you must arrange your source files in package structure, and then call `javac` from the root of this structure. For example this way:

- *root directory*

  - `oop`

    - `ex1`

      - `filters`

        - `Writeable.java`
        - `IllegalFilterArgumentException.java`

Then you'll call it this way:

```
javac oop/ex1/filters/Writable.java
```

Alternatively to "calling from the *root directory*" you could pass this root directory as an option to javac:

```
javac -sourcepath "root directory" oop/ex1/filters/Writable.java
```

(You may also want to give other options to `javac`, look at its help page.)